# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Upgrade Routing from 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I am upgrading my application from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2. There is a change in the routing that I am having problems with. I have reviewed the following links as a source.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/27/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-endpoint-routing/

Here is my Core 2.1 code in Startup.cs

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //Area Marketing
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Marketing",
            template: "Marketing/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            //Area Media
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Media",
            template: "Media/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            //Area Membership
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Membership",
            template: "Membership/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            //Area Military
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Military",
            template: "Military/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");


            //Area Process
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Process",
            template: "Process/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

Here is my Core 2.2 code in Startup.cs that I have migrated.

```
        //ASP.NET Core 2.2 Routes
        var routes = new RouteBuilder(app);
        //
        //routes.DefaultHandler = new MvcRouteHandler(???);
        //
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        //Area Marketing
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Marketing",
        template: "Marketing/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

        //Area Media
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Media",
        template: "Media/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

        //Area Membership
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Membership",
        template: "Membership/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

        //Area Military
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Military",
        template: "Military/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");


        //Area Process
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Process",
        template: "Process/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        app.UseRouter(routes.Build());
    }
```

When I run the applicaiton I get the following error: 
[image]

It looks like I need to create or setup a Handler for this. What would my Handler code look like as there are not any examples or tutorials that I can find.

Comment: The docs say "MapRoute only adds routes that are handled by the DefaultHandler". So you'll have to create the ```RouteBuilder``` with this default ```RouteHandler``` as the second parameter. Then MapRoute will work.

Comment: I do not find your answer detailed enough. Please provide an example.

Comment: This should do the job:
```
var routes = new RouteBuilder(app, app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MvcRouteHandler>());
```